# Firebase in Java/Android: The transaction was overridden by a subsequent set

Tags: java, android, exception, firebase

My multiplayer game using Firebase SDK for Java/Android has game rooms where 4 players can play together.

In order to implement the matchmaking, I have a Firebase reference for every room that players can join to. Each of these references has 4 slots (as child nodes) containing the UUIDs of the players that are taking part or an empty string if the slot is still available.

In order to prevent two (or more) players from claiming the same slot simultanteously, I'm using transactions. Is the following code correct for that purpose?

```
private int mUserSlot;

firebaseReference.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

    @Override
    public Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
        for (int s = 0; s <= 3; s++) { // loop through all slots
            final String slotValue = currentData.child(slotFromLocalID(s)).getValue(String.class);
            if (slotValue == null || slotValue.equals("") || slotValue.equals(mUserUUID)) { // if slot is still available
                currentData.child(slotFromLocalID(s)).setValue(mUserUUID);
                mUserSlot = s;
                return Transaction.success(currentData);
            }
        }
        return Transaction.abort();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError error, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
        if (error == null) {
            if (committed) {
                System.out.println("User is now in slot "+mUserSlot);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("User could not join, all slots occupied");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: "+error.getMessage());
        }
    }

});
```

However, I'm throwing an `Exception` in the `error != null` branch in `onComplete()` above for debugging and after some test runs, I could see the following error message (from `error.getMessage()` in my debug logs:

```
The transaction was overridden by a subsequent set
```

What does that mean, exactly? I thought the transactions are to prevent concurrent access to the same fields which overwrite each other. Could that mean that some other part of the application is writing to that field *without* a transaction?

In this case, can I just handle it as I do with `!committed`? That means, in both cases, the value that I wanted to write is not there after the transaction has completed, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that message means that one of your clients is writing to the same location using `set` instead of `transaction` which aborts the transaction. I would highly recommend not using `set` on a location where transactions are being used.